# Will PGP signed email be blocked in China?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature, international

I generally sign all of my outgoing email with PGP. I don't usually encrypt it because most people I send mail to don't have a public key. Anyway, if I send an unencrypted message with a PGP signature to someone in China, will it get blocked or get them into trouble with the government?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would -- at least not any regular person who isn't already under a watchful eye of law enforcement. China doesn't block encrypted communication, it just makes it inconvenient for people to use (e.g. you can use https when accessing non-Chinese sites while in China, it's just throttled to all heck, in the hopes to force you to use cleartext protocols). China's mass-filtering program is not really aimed at individual users, as much as it attempts to limit access to "undesirable resources" (pornography, anti-Chinese materials, etc). I've sent PGP-signed email to people in China on a routine basis (we host a few servers in Beijing, so I communicate with support staff all the time), and at no point this was any cause of problem.